# In keras how call add function [a3,a8]

Tags: keras, addition

```
d1 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3))(a5)
a6 = Activation('relu')(d1)

m1 = add([a4, a6])
a7 = Activation('relu')(m1)

d2 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3))(a7)
a8 = Activation('relu')(d2)

m2 = add([a3, a8])
a9 = Activation('relu')(m2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is from ResNet implementation in keras. Here the skip connections are using `layers.add` function.

```
def identity_block(input_tensor, kernel_size, filters, stage, block):
    """The identity block is the block that has no conv layer at shortcut.

    # Arguments
        input_tensor: input tensor
        kernel_size: default 3, the kernel size of middle conv layer at main path
        filters: list of integers, the filters of 3 conv layer at main path
        stage: integer, current stage label, used for generating layer names
        block: 'a','b'..., current block label, used for generating layer names

    # Returns
        Output tensor for the block.
    """
    filters1, filters2, filters3 = filters
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_last':
        bn_axis = 3
    else:
        bn_axis = 1
    conv_name_base = 'res' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'
    bn_name_base = 'bn' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'

    x = Conv2D(filters1, (1, 1), name=conv_name_base + '2a')(input_tensor)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name=bn_name_base + '2a')(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters2, kernel_size,
               padding='same', name=conv_name_base + '2b')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name=bn_name_base + '2b')(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters3, (1, 1), name=conv_name_base + '2c')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name=bn_name_base + '2c')(x)

    x = layers.add([x, input_tensor])
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    return x
```

[image: resnet]

As given in the documentation,

`It takes as input a list of tensors, all of the same shape, and returns a single tensor (also of the same shape).`

If you want to add `x1` and `x2` to form a new layer (which is done in ResNets) you can do something like this

```
added = keras.layers.Add()([x1, x2])
```

or

```
added = keras.layers.add([x1, x2])
```

Then you can treat `added` as a layer output and build other layers on top of it.

Hope this helps!